# List of valid states in boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, boto3

I want to list all stacks that do not have `DELETE_COMPLETE` as stack status

Using `boto2` it was very easy:

```py
import boto
cf = boto.cloudformation.connect_to_region(region)
status_filter = [st for st in cf.valid_states if st != 'DELETE_COMPLETE']
for stack in cf.list_stacks(stack_status_filters=status_filter):
    ...
```

`boto3` use botocore with many service-2.json files for every AWS service. But I can't find any list all possible status flags.

I can find this in the service-2.json (botocore/data/cloudformation/2010-05-15/service-2.json) but how is the right way to access this list?

Getting all stacks and then skip stacks that have DELETE_COMPLETE as status in the for loop is not an option.

Comment: I would consider retrieving *all* stacks (using no filter) and then simply filter them client-side to strip out DELETE_COMPLETE stacks. It will probably be faster too.

Comment: this is the simple way, but on high frequented stacks is this a long list.

AWS holds 'DELETE_COMPLETE' 90 days

Comment: If you genuinely have a performance issue with list_stacks for all states then you may just have to hard-code the full list of states in the filter, minus DELETE_COMPLETE.